# Calculate time.Time from timestamp starting from 1601-01-01 in Go

Tags: datetime, go, time

I'm trying to parse .ndx file. Which contains a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).
Here's implementation in python: https://github.com/mekh/jtv2xmltv/blob/master/jtv2xml.py#L31

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var timestamp int64
    timestamp = 132118740000000000

    delta := time.Duration(timestamp)*time.Microsecond
    fmt.Println(delta)

    seconds, _ := divmod(timestamp, 1000000)
    hours, seconds := divmod(seconds, 3600)
    delta = time.Duration(hours)*time.Hour
    fmt.Println(delta)

    layout := "2006-01-02"
    start, _ := time.Parse(layout, "1601-01-01")

    fmt.Println(start.Add(delta))
}

func divmod(numerator, denominator int64) (quotient, remainder int64) {
    quotient = numerator / denominator // integer division, decimals are truncated
    remainder = numerator % denominator
    return
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/--zQUtJN5Lh

Looks like delta variable overflows, even when setting by hours. Is there any way to calculate this?

**EDIT**: Found in docs https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration

> A Duration represents the elapsed time between two instants as an int64 nanosecond count. The representation limits the largest representable duration to approximately 290 years.

Is there any 3rd party packages for duration longer than 290 years?

**EDIT2**: in the end I need time.Time of a given timestamp

Comment: Requests for third-party packages are off-topic here.

Comment: But a simple solution might be to store a `time.Duration`, along with a multiplier. If you need a 3,000-year duration, you can store a `time.Duration` of 30 years, and a multiplier of 10x, for instance. In other cases, if all you care about is the number of years, a simple `int` could work. Whether either works for you depends on what operations you're doing on your duration variables.

Comment: As you quoted, `time.Duration` cannot represent durations larger than 290 years. So what do you want then? The values of hours, minutes, seconds since `1601-01-01` of the given timestamp; or a `time.Time` value representing that timestamp or what? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Btw your example timestamp looks "short", it designates the year 1642. If you add a 0 to it: `132118740000000000`, then it will be `2019-09-02`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) is an `int64` value representing a duration in nanoseconds. As stated, max value of `int64` is about 290 years, so bigger durations cannot be represented by it.

### Simplest, naive solution

One simple solution is to convert your input to `time.Duration`, which will represent one hundredth of your actual duration, because the input is in 100-nanosecond units. You may add this duration to a time starting with the reference date: `1601-01-01 UTC` a hundred times, and you're done:

```
func getTime(input int64) time.Time {
    t := time.Date(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    d := time.Duration(input)
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        t = t.Add(d)
    }
    return t
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(getTime(132118740000000000))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pzuiZ5pJrJN)):

```
2019-09-02 05:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

### Naive solution optimized

Yes, the above solution has a loop with 100 iterations, which may not be optimal.

One way to speed up the above is to reduce the number of iterations. We may do so if the input is not "very" large. For example if the input multiplied by 2 also fits into `int64`, we could pre-multiply it by `2`, and then we would only need 50 iterations. Similarly, if the `input*10` would also fit into `int64`, we could pre-multiply it by `10` and then we would only need 10 iterations.

The input is 100-nanosecond units. `100` is dividable by 100, 50, 25, 20, 10, 5, 4, 2, so to not lose any nanoseconds, we could check these factors if the input multiplied by these still fits into `int64`, and if so we can divide the iterations count by it. In the best case scenario (if duration is less than 2.9 years, we can reduce the iterations to 1).

Example doing so:

```
var divisors = []int64{100, 50, 25, 20, 10, 5, 4, 2}

func getTime(input int64) time.Time {
    iterations := 100
    for _, div := range divisors {
        if input <= math.MaxInt64/div {
            input *= div
            iterations /= int(div)
            break
        }
    }

    t := time.Date(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    d := time.Duration(input)
    for i := 0; i < iterations; i++ {
        t = t.Add(d)
    }
    return t
}
```

This will output the same, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-USoNVHRmO3). In this example the number of iterations is only 2.

### Fewest iterations

Similar to the above solution, but here in each iteration we will increment the time with the biggest duration possible. That is: `time.Duration(math.MaxInt64)`, but since the input is in 100-nanosecond units, to be exact, we'll use `time.Duration(math.MaxInt64).Truncate(100 * time.Nanosecond)`. We keep doing this until the remaining duration is less than the maximum, which will be the final addition to get the time instant we're looking for. As an extra, we also don't need the first loop which looked for the biggest divisor (to which the iterations count could be reduced).

```
func getTime(input int64) time.Time {
    maxd := time.Duration(math.MaxInt64).Truncate(100 * time.Nanosecond)
    maxdUnits := int64(maxd / 100) // number of 100-ns units

    t := time.Date(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    for input > maxdUnits {
        t = t.Add(maxd)
        input -= maxdUnits
    }
    if input != 0 {
        t = t.Add(time.Duration(input * 100))
    }
    return t
}
```

Output again is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZPGsxOmRjrW).

This solution guarantees fewest iterations. E.g. if duration is less than 290 years, there will be a single `time.Add()` call. If duration is between 290 and 580 years, there will be 2 `time.Add()` calls etc.

Note that in the final `time.Add()` call we multiply `input` by `100` to convert 100-nanosecond units to nanoseconds. This will always succeed, because the loop before that decrements it as long as its bigger than `maxdUnits`. We also only call this final `time.Add()` if there is still something left to add, to ensure the fewest iterations. In practice this will likely always be true, so this `if` could be left out: even if `input` is 0, adding zero will not change `t`, I added it to be true to the "fewest iterations" title.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the dates before, say 1900, why not shift the date to 1900?

So you take the int64 from the ndx, shift it by the diffs from 1601 to 1900, divide it by 100, and then calculate based on your new epoch.  No loop, and should be pretty fast and accurate

Answer (score -1):

Found another solution using syscall.Filetime: https://parsiya.net/blog/2018-11-01-windows-filetime-timestamps-and-byte-wrangling-with-go/

```
// toTime converts an 8-byte Windows Filetime to time.Time.
func toTime(t [8]byte) time.Time {
    ft := &syscall.Filetime{
        LowDateTime:  binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(t[:4]),
        HighDateTime: binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(t[4:]),
    }
    return time.Unix(0, ft.Nanoseconds())
}
```